# Mozilla Firefox’s WebSocket implementation

Tags: jquery, web-services, firefox, websocket, firefox-os

I’m creating a `window.WebSocket` object by passing `ws://URI` in the constructor in my jQuery. And then sending the JSON message using this object’s send call.

But in browser’s developer tools, the request URI is `http` while I created the object with `ws` URI.

I want to know, is Mozilla Firefox’s WebSocket implementation passing `http` as URI instead of `ws`?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are not just seeing the WebSocket Protocol handshake?
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/an-introduction-to-websockets
See the 101 response
[image]

Comment: Hi, Yes websocket protocol handshake is happening properly. Just want to know that If I create window.WebSocket object by passing 'ws://URI' in the constructor. The request URI send from the browser will be 'http:// URI' having upgrade header ? (The browser will send http uri and not ws uri ? )

Comment: Pretty certain that is the case.  That example was setup like: var socket = new WebSocket('ws://echo.websocket.org'); and it sent the http request with upgrade.